# - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, appdelegate

I want to cancel url connection when `applicationDidEnterBackground` is called. But I don't know how to save a connection in a whole scope of application. I created a few url connections in other view controllers, but I'd like to cancel them in `AppDelegate`. How can I do this?

Comment: I am pretty sure url connections will stop anyway when the app closes, and ARC should take care of the rest.

Comment: Will it restart automatically when app applicationWillEnterForeground?  Is there any document I can reference?

Answer (score 3):

You may add observer to `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` in your class which create the connection. Try this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(enterBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

remember call this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

in your class's `dealloc`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your NSURLConnections will be killed when your app enters the background.

If you want to keep track of all NSURLConnections, you need to keep track of them yourself by adding them to a NSSet, NSArray, or some other datastructure, and looping through them closing them.  You could also have a class that inherits or composes a NSURLConnection.  This datastructure would handle adding itself to a queue, and you could clean up when the app exits.

Comment: Is there any proof to show me of NSURLConnections will be killed when app enters the background. I tried to find some document to support this but failed.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to stop the connections before app becomes inactive instead of **applicationDidEnterBackground**.

Answer is use notifications:

```
-(void)init
{
//
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(closeConnection) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
//
}
-(void)closeConnections
{
// [urlConnection cancel];
}
```

Comment: The app's state will applicationWillResignActive when a call comes, and will applicationDidEnterBackground when answering the call while applicationDidBecomeActive when rejecting the call.  I think it's better to comfirm the state and stop the connection.